# RTL8821CE on Dell Vostro 15 3515 Bluetooth coexistence (WiFi stops working when I use Bluetooth)

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, dell, realtek-wireless

A Dell Vostro 15 3515 comes with Ubuntu 20.04 preinstalled. It mostly works great. The earlier problem people had with Realtek RTL8821CE seem to be resolved since both WiFI and Bluetooth work. Except... not at the same time.

[hw-probe output](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=722f543885).

The moment I connect to Bluetooth speakers, WiFI becomes very unreliable and slow with pings going from ~50ms to ~10s.

For other wireless cards people suggest setting various parameters for the WiFi driver so that it can cooperate with the Bluetooth one and work on non-overlapping frequencies. However, for `modinfo -p rtw88_8821ce` there is an empty output suggesting it does not support this.

Should I try other drivers? From the preliminary research it seems that various DKMS drivers exist for RTL8821CE. The preinstalled one comes from linux-modules-5.14.0-1045-oem package.

Comment: I think the only working option is to switch to 5GHz Wi-Fi.

Comment: +1000 for 5 gHz, however, you will probably need to rename the SSID in the router; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

Comment: Too bad my router does not support 5GHz. Guess I'll have to get a new one.

Comment: In the meantime, I suggest that you try a fixed channel in the router, rather than auto channel select. I'd try 1, 6 or 11. My 2.4 gHz segment is set to channel 11 and I have no issues at all with bluetooth.

Comment: @chili555 moving to channel 11 worked. Would you like to submit that as an answer?

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth operates in the 2.4 gHz band, often overlapping with wifi. Since you don't have 5 gHz available, I suggest that you set your router to use a fixed channel, rather than auto channel select, and try the highest channel available; either 11 or, if it's available in your country, 13.

After making these changes, reboot the router.